# Rewriting in simple theorem proof

Tags: proof, dependent-type, idris, theorem-proving, formal-verification

I wrote a definition of [group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)) in Idris:

```
data Group: Type -> Type where
    Unit: (x: t) -> Group t
    (*): Group t -> Group t -> Group t
    Inv: Group t -> Group t
postulate
    assoc: (a : Group t) -> (b : Group t) -> (c : Group t) -> ((a*b)*c = a*(b*c))
postulate
    neutralL: (x: t) -> (a : Group t) -> a * Unit x = a
postulate
    neutralR: (x: t) -> (a : Group t) -> Unit x * a = a
postulate
    invUnitL: (x: t) -> (a : Group t) -> a * (Inv a) = Unit x
postulate
    invUnitR: (x: t) -> (a : Group t) -> (Inv a) * a = Unit x
```

Then I proved a couple of simple propositions:

```
cong : (a : Group t) -> (b : Group t) -> (c: Group t) -> a = b -> a*c = b*c
cong a b c post = rewrite post in Refl

neutralL1: (x: t) -> (a : Group t) -> a = a * Unit x
neutralL1 x a = rewrite neutralL x a in Refl

neutralR1: (x: t) -> (a : Group t) -> a = Unit x * a
neutralR1 x a = rewrite neutralR x a in Refl
```

However, I have a problem with proving that there is only one unit element:

```
singleUnit : (x: t) -> (y: t) -> (Unit x = Unit y)
```

I tried various expressions using a general idea, that `Unit x` = (by `neutralL1 y (Unit x)`) = `Unit x * Unit y` = (by `neutralR x (Unit y)`) = `Unit y`, but with no success:

```
singleUnit x y = rewrite neutralL1 y (Unit x) in neutralR x (Unit y)
singleUnit x y = rewrite neutralL1 y (Unit x) in rewrite neutralR x (Unit y) in Refl
singleUnit x y = rewrite neutralR x (Unit y) in neutralL1 y (Unit x)
singleUnit x y = rewrite neutralR x (Unit y) in rewrite neutralL1 y (Unit x) in Refl
```

How can I prove this?
I have a feeling, that the problem here is related to substitution of complex expressions, like `Unit x * Unit y`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this definition of a group won't work. In general, you have to be *very* careful introducing new axioms (postulates).

E.g. it's easy to see that `neutralL` violates the principle of disjointness of (different) data constructors, i.e. `Constr1 <data> != Constr2 <data>`.

```
starAndUnitAreDisjoint : (*) a (Unit x) = a -> Void
starAndUnitAreDisjoint Refl impossible
```

Now we can prove false:

```
contradiction : Void
contradiction = starAndUnitAreDisjoint $ neutralL Z (Unit Z)
```

Finita la commedia!

What you actually want is a `record` or a typeclass, see e.g. [contrib/Control/Algebra.idr](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/e819e6bff4052ff0703db7c87ec5198155962b3a/libs/contrib/Control/Algebra.idr#L19) and [contrib/Interfaces/Verified.idr](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/e819e6bff4052ff0703db7c87ec5198155962b3a/libs/contrib/Interfaces/Verified.idr#L121). In addition, Agda versions are syntactically pretty close to Idris ([agda-stdlib/src/Algebra.agda](https://github.com/agda/agda-stdlib/blob/7205fba80a8739d5852018d02fb360ee5ed4862c/src/Algebra.agda) and probably the [Abstract Algebra in Agda](http://people.inf.elte.hu/divip/AgdaTutorial/Application.Algebra.html) tutorial) -- you might want to have a look at them.

Answer (score 2):

Your group definition is structured in a way that would make sense if it was an interface. I have rewritten it as follows, keeping your original variable and function names as much as possible:

```
%default total

interface Group t where
  Unit: t
  (*): t -> t -> t
  Inv: t -> t

  assoc: (a : t) -> (b : t) -> (c : t) -> ((a*b)*c = a*(b*c))
  neutralL: (x: t) -> (a : t) -> a * Unit = a
  neutralR: (x: t) -> (a : t) -> Unit * a = a
  invUnitL: (x: t) -> (a : t) -> a * (Inv a) = Unit
  invUnitR: (x: t) -> (a : t) -> (Inv a) * a = Unit

cong : Group t => (a : t) -> (b : t) -> (c: t) -> a = b -> a*c = b*c
cong a b c post = rewrite post in Refl

neutralL1: Group t => (x: t) -> (a : t) -> a = a * Unit
neutralL1 x a = rewrite neutralL x a in Refl

neutralR1: Group t => (x: t) -> (a : t) -> a = Unit * a
neutralR1 x a = rewrite neutralR x a in Refl

is_left_unit : Group t => (x : t) -> Type
is_left_unit x = (y : t) -> x * y = y

only_one_left_unit : Group t => (x : t) -> is_left_unit x -> x = Unit
only_one_left_unit x is_left_unit_x = 
  let x_times_unit_is_unit = is_left_unit_x Unit in
  let x_times_unit_is_x = neutralL Unit x in
    trans (sym x_times_unit_is_x) x_times_unit_is_unit

is_right_unit : Group t => (x : t) -> Type
is_right_unit x = (y : t) -> y * x = y

only_one_right_unit : Group t => (x : t) -> is_right_unit x -> x = Unit
only_one_right_unit x is_right_unit_x = 
  let unit_times_x_is_unit = is_right_unit_x Unit in
  let unit_times_x_is_x = neutralR Unit x in
    trans (sym unit_times_x_is_x) unit_times_x_is_unit
```

You'll notice that the type `t` actually is the group type, and `Unit` is a value rather than a function with one parameter. I have defined separate functions `is_left_unit` and `is_right_unit` representing the notions of being a left or right unit respectively.

To be sure all this makes sense we would want to define some actual concrete group, supplying implementations for `Unit`, `*` and `Inv`, and additionally supplying implementations for `assoc`, `neutralL`, `neutralR`, `invUnitL` and `invUnitR` which represent proof obligations.